# Is the function differentiable when $x=0$

Tags: calculus

I have the function $f(x) = -x^2$ if $x \leq0$ and $x^2$ if $x>0$ (sorry i didn't know how to put the large curly bracket on the left but it is meant to be there and all one function) also written as $x|x|$.
Is this function differentiable at $0$, as i am getting contradicting answers from people on my course. I believe it should be differentiable as if you take the left and right derivative, they are both $0$ however people on my course seem to believe that the limits stated make this untrue. If it is untrue then why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h|h|-0|0|}h=\lim_{h\to 0}|h|=0,$$ full stop.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\vert f(x) \vert \le \vert x \vert \vert x \vert$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

As $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \vert x \vert =0$$

by definition of the derivative, you get that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and that $f^\prime(0)=0$. You don’t even need to consider left and right derivative in that case.

Comment: I don't see why you need the initial inequality.

Comment: Why is that better than considering the left and right derivatives?

Comment: Because just applying the definition of the derivative, separating left and right cases is useless. Obviously, this is a subjective topic...

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean that equality is enough?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: if $f$ is continuous at $x$, and its left and right derivatives are equal at $x$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Yes, you can compute the exact value of the rate of variation ftrom $0$ with the alternative definition of the function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I agree that it's subjective: my view is that comparing the left and right derivatives is a "high-level" geometric approach to the problem, while an $\epsilon/\delta$ argument is "low-level".